# Access local host website in Android device through wifi

Tags: android, iis, web, localhost

I am developing one website which is need to host in local system and access this website in all device through WiFi. My system in which I publish website in IIS is Connected in LAN. And WiFi is also from same router.

I need to access this website in all device which is connected in WiFi. How can I achieve this? If you have any other suggestion to do this than than please let me know.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to add an inbound rule in the firewall for port 80 (or whatever port you used for your website on IIS):

- Go to Control Panel, Windows Firewall
- Select Inbound Rules
- Add a New Rule

  - Select "Port" as a Rule Type
  - Select "TCP and put "80" (and any    other ports you want to open) in "Specific local ports"
  - Select "Allow the connection"
  - Select the network location where the rule should apply
  - Give a name and an optional description

After that you should be able to access your site from other devices in the same network using `http://computername` (e.g. `http://myhomepc`)

Comment: Thank you. i follow this step. i can now access website through lan but for WiFi i have give IP Address instead of Computer Name. And If i give IP Address than i can access website in my mobile but Web Service Not Working which is already host in Same System. –

Comment: Android always seems to override its DNS entries using Google's servers. Try to modify DNS settings as explained at http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/52140/how-to-reach-local-computer-via-machine-name-instead-of-ip

Comment: I have infact disabled firewall of the computer but still accessing via ip address from android device does not help. As i have disabled my computer firewall, your above steps are not to be performed altogether. In short , i am unable to access a website hosted on IIS on lan network from my mobile using wifi of same network. How do i resolve as i am finding this strange.

Answer (score -1):

go to windows firewall and 
just turn off firewall for "Public Network Setting" ... 
now u will access your website using ip of current pc 
like http://192.168.1.200/SOCH/ ..... 
SOCH is my project folder